Actuator prometheus endpoint returns empty response
I upgraded my project to springboot 3 and suddenly the actuator/prometheus endpoint stopped returning any content even though I got a 200 status code. The prometheus endpoint is exposed when I checked the /actuator endpoint:
Actuator endpoints
Here are the actuator and micrometer prometheus dependencies I included in the project:
implementation "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus"
implementation "io.micrometer:micrometer-core"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:3.1.10"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:3.1.10"


My application.properties file has the following configurations:
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=env,info,prometheus,health
management.prometheus.metrics.export.enabled=true
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true


I sent a GET request to localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus from the browser and postman yet the response was empty: Request sent from browser request sent from postman
Is there something I may be missing?

Please check which version of Micrometer is used. Are you creating the PrometheusMeterRegistry or do you let Boot to create it for you?

@JonatanIvanov I didn't manually create the PrometheusMeterRegistry. I'm using the one created by Springboot. The Micrometer version generated is 1.11.0

Could you please try to generate a project using start.spring.io and see if that works? Then try to bring the two apps closer together and check where the prometheus endpoint breaks (will be empty).
